# Show all geopoints of parse.com in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, parse-platform, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to take all the geopoints from a class in parse.com and show them as markers in a google map. (about only 1 geoipoin, lat lng, is working like a charm so here is the code)

```
 function businessProfile(uid) {
      Parse.initialize("APPID", "JSKEY");
      var bprofile = Parse.Object.extend("magazia");
      var query = new Parse.Query(bprofile);
      query.notEqualTo("objectId", null);
      query.find({
          success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { var object = results[i];
                  var locationsBlock = {};
                  locationsBlock = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
                  var location = {};
                  location = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationsBlock.latlon));
                  var lat = location.latitude;
                  var lon = location.longitude;
                  var magname = object.get('name');
                  setData(magname, lat, lon);
              }


          },
         error: function(error) {

              alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
      });
  }
```

So with the code above i get all the geopoints of 16 different rows and i push them into an array (i hope i do it properly), which array is declared outside of the function because i call it again on the map initialiazation function below.

```
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 34.9, lng: 111.2}
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}
function setData(magname, lat, lon){
    var arlat = [];
arlat.push(magname, lat, lon);
console.log(arlat);
}
function setMarkers(map) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arlat.length; i++) {
    var arlat = arlat[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: arlat[1], lng: arlat[2]},
      map: map,
      title: arlat[0]

    });
  }
}
```

So now i'm stuck on how to place each geopoint into the map with markers.
I know it has to do with the "for loop" but i'm stucked there. Now it shows only the first on the list marker, and i want to show them all.

**UPDATE**

So one update on my code i've managed to pass all the names and the lat lon that i get from my class in parse and now i put them in the `function setData()`

Now the question is, how can i pass the arlat array in the `setMarkers()` since the setMarkers function takes the `map` variable from the `initMap()` and i want it to take also the `arlat` array from the `setData()` function so i can print in the right section the lat lon and name? Here is a preview of the `console.log(arlat)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing three variables:

```
arlat.push(magname, lat, lon);
```

You probably should [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) an object, like this:

```
 arlat.push({lat: lat, lon: lon});
```

Then We just need to iterate over the pins (you could do it with a for loop, but a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) might be simpler because you don't have to index into the array, just use a callback function that accepts the array element)...

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'marker.png',

    title: 'Hello World!'
});
arlat.forEach(function(positionObject) {
    var pin = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: positionObject.lat,
            lon: positionObject.lon
        },
        map: map,
        //title: positionObject.title, //if title property is set above
        icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|00ff00' //green pin, more available
    });
});
```

Does that work for you? For more info about icons, checkout the [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex) (which you likely already have looked at)

**UPDATE** - based on your update, I noticed you are reassigning the value of arlat, which conflicts with the foreach iterations. I have changed it to use objects, and not overwrite the array object - see [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xZuqRO0ngzNQ0fbHB04z?p=preview) or the code snippet below.

```js
function initialize() {
  var arlat = [];
  setData('a', 34.0, 111.2);
  setData('v', 30.1, 116.3);
  initMap();

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {
        lat: 34.9,
        lng: 111.2
      }
    });
    setMarkers(map);
  }

  function setData(magname, lat, lon) {
    //notice how we name the properties below: name, lat, lon - these are referenced down below in setMarkers()
    arlat.push({
      name: magname,
      lat: lat,
      lon: lon
    });
  }

  function setMarkers(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arlat.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: arlat[i].lat,
          lng: arlat[i].lon
        },
        map: map,
        title: arlat[i].name
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your example takes again only the first result and i get the console message "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: Also you have left the first marker and if i comment it out to take the rest of the code the positionObject is not defined :/

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but in your example you set the data by yourself, `setData('a',34.0,111.2);
  setData('v',30.1,116.3);`  this is where i'm stucked, to take all the names and lat lon from parse. Could you update the code also about the parse code please?

Comment: You should be able to call that same function setData() like you have in your success callback in the businessProfile() function ... does that make sense? `setData(magname, lat, lon);`

Comment: I do this but i get an error on the success function that setData() is not defined.

Comment: okay - try moving the function definition businessProfile() (or the call to it) down after the definition of setData()...

Comment: I see you are defining magname as `var magname = object.get('name');` - and object comes inside the iterator (`var object = results[i];`) - I am not really familiar with the Parse library but as long as the results is actually an array of results then object should be an actual object... That is about all I can say, given the code you supplied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102405/discussion-between-aelliott1485-and-kwnstantinos-natsios).